# Is it possible to pass more than one argument to pandas converters (read_csv)?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, lambda

I have a CSV file that I need to read as a DataFrame, but I'd like to apply a transformation in one of the columns using `converters` from `pandas.read_csv`.

This is what's in my file:

```py
                       matrix  size
"(1, 2, 3, 4)"                    2
"(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)"     3
```

The strings in `matrix` need to be converted to matrices according to the corresponding size. (The actual process is more complex and the values in the data actually correspond to the lower triangle of each matrix, etc.)

So, the expected output DataFrame is:

```py
                              matrix   size  
0  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]                       2

1  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, ...      3
```

I'm trying to use `converters` to convert the columns as I read them.

For example, if I wanted to read the strings in matrix as simple arrays, I could do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
converters = {'matrix': lambda x: np.fromstring(x[1:-1], sep=',').astype('int64')}
```

And then read the file passing this dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', converters=converters)
```

The output would be:

```py
                        matrix   size  
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]                     2

1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]      3
```

In my case, I have a function to transform the strings to matrices:

```py
def array_to_matrix(array_str, size):
    array = np.fromstring(array_str[1:-1], sep=',').astype('int64')
    return array.reshape(size, size)
```

But this function requires two arguments.

I can parse the matrix columns by doing this:

```py
df['matrix'] = df.apply(lambda x: array_to_matrix(x['matrix'], x['size']), axis=1)
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to parse the matrices using converters. To use converters, I could do the following:

```py
matrix_converters = dict([('matrix', lambda x, y: array_to_matrix(x, y))])
```

But `x` will become the value in `matrix` (the dictionary key) and I have no way to pass `y`.

My use case is more complex and would benefit from being able to parse many similar columns while reading the file.

Is it possible to pass more than one column in the DataFrame to converters, or is it limited to one?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
df.matrix = df.apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x[0])).reshape((x[1], x[1])), axis=1)
```

or of the matrix is not square:

```py
df.matrix = df.apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x[0])).reshape((x[1], -1)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
print(df)

                              matrix  size
0                   [[1, 2], [3, 4]]     2
1  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]     3
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't specific enough in my question. I want to do the same using the converters option in the read_csv function of pandas. I'll edit the question to make it clear.